# Rest design - Multiple calls vs returning all data in one call

Tags: rest

I am trying to build a rest API for an android app. Suppose I have a `users` table with `(id, name, email)` and a `songs` table with `(id, song_name, album)` and a rich join association between them as `streams` having `(user_id, song_id, listen_count)`. I want to fetch details about all the streams and show it in the app as a list. The list would be showing the song name, album name, user name and listen count. I see three plausible options -

1. `GET` to `/streams` and fetch a list of all the `song_ids` and `user_ids`. Then make `GET` to `/user/:id` and `/song/:id` for each user and song id to get the user and song information.
2. `GET` to `/streams` and fetch a list of all the `user_ids` and `song_ids`. Then one `GET` to `/user?ids=<comma_separated_ids>` to fetch information about all the users and a `GET` to `song?ids=<comma_separated_ids>` to fetch information about all the songs.
3. `GET` to `/streams` and fetch everything in one call. Something like -

   ```
   [

     {

       "user_id" : 10,
       "song_id" : 14,
       "listen_count" : 5,
       "user" : {
         "id"     : 10,
         "name"   : "bla", 
         "email"  : "bla",
       },
       "song" : {
         "id"     : 14,
         "name"   : "blu",
         "album"  : "blu"
      }
     },
   ...
   ]
   ```

I'm tempted to go with option 3 because it gives me everything in one call, but I don't think it's very rest-full and I fear that it won't be scalable. Option 2 is good but it takes 3 calls which would mean considerable time loading the list. And option 1 follows rest but will take numerous calls for showing the list and doing so many calls from a mobile device isn't feasible.

What would be the recommended way to go about this?

Comment: Rest-like and salable are two different things.

Comment: @RobertHarvey how do you mean?

Comment: What makes you think the quality of your REST interface affects the salability of a product?  Are you actually selling the REST interface?  If you aren't, nobody cares what's under the hood.  See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142353

Comment: There's singificant overhead in making a REST call.  Consequently, there's a strong possibility that 3 is the best approach from a scalability standpoint, especially if you use all of the data so returned.

Comment: Related in a way http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/257408/56903

Comment: Have a look a OData, if you haven't seen it already. A good way to layer on top of REST, and provide for filters, nested data, even doing joins, from an API perspective. For example, http://stackoverflow.com/q/3920758/471129 gives a good discussion about using navigational properties for specific joins without having to introduce foreign keys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When creating a REST interface, there is no requirement, or even expectation, that the responses on the REST interface correspond directly to tables or joins in the database.

Your `/streams` interface can just as easily be represented as

```
[
  {
    "listen_count" : 5,
    "user" : {
      "href"     : "/users/10",
      "name"   : "bla", 
    },
    "song" : {
      "href"     : "/songs/14",
      "name"   : "blu",
      "album"  : "blu"
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

Where the JSON objects contain the main details of users and songs that are (nearly) always relevant for consumers of a stream resource, and a link to the relevant user/song resources if further details are needed.

This is essentially a variation of your third option, with a fallback to option 1 if more details are needed.

Comment: There is no guarranted answer to me folks... option 3 could be simple if the domains remains simple but it will get you in trouble for objects that beholds more than two levels of aggretations. For example, you want to retrieve all the avaiable Courses with of data of their teacher. You have `Course` -> `Teacher` (information about the person as a teacher, stored in a separeted table) -> `Person` (the physical person, as you can recall the same person could be a teacher of several Courses). Option 2 is scalable, and requires * request. Also opt. 1 is scalable too, but it could need >> request.

Comment: So to synthethise the above comment: if you looking for efficiency, then strive for number 1, but if you looking for a system that could grow without problems in time (scalability) without giving headache, aim for option 1 or 2. It is worth to mention that premature optimiization is the root of evil... so this is warning to option 3.

Comment: need to correct myself above.. "if you looking for efficiency, then strive for number 3"

Answer (score 3):

You definitely want a single `GET` operation that returns **metadata** about each song and user in addition to their opaque ids.

- As you pointed out, it's much simpler. That is a good thing.
- Making one of the most common operations for your client apps a single server request instead of O(n) requests is *much* more scalable. In the long run, the network will be your biggest bottleneck, so you don't want to send any more requests than you have to.
- The ids by themselves are kinda useless except for making additional REST calls.
- As long as your metadata has a relatively small and bounded size (e.g. no pages of descriptive text or actual audio files, just names, types, counts and so on) returning it in addition to the ids is unlikely to be a performance issue.

Comment: Interesting. But option 3 doesn't really adhere to a `rest-full` design does it? A `GET` to `streams` *should* return all the `streams` and nothing else(even if they are just ids and useless to the client).

Comment: @zack In the strictest sense, yes, but any design principle can be taken too far. When you find yourself arguing the program *should* do something *useless*, that's usually not a good sign.

Comment: Metadata is data about data, this is just data.

Comment: @zack: A `streams` resource can logically contain (parts of) other resources. Things that are logically part of a resource should be present in the representation of that resource.

Comment: @zack option 3 is completely 100% RESTful. The Resources you expose via your API have zero requirement to relate to anything else in your system, including your DB tables and your domain model. You could have 3 database tables and 600 resources if that made sense for your web app. There is no requirement to represent your DB relationships in your Resources relationships.